# Intel graphics causes "speckles" on screen

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, screen-corruption

Have just freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04, the screen is corrupted with 'speckles'. Screenshot below, [Full resolution here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ryoo3e5evks5bl/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-19%2017:02:09.png). Graphics chipset is Intel HD Graphics 2500

[image: Corrupted display]

Windows 7 installation on same machine exhibits no problems, have tried different HDMI cables and DVI connection with no improvement. Only solution so far is to completely remove the distribution-supplied intel drivers and use software rendering, though this is not satisfactory.

```
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
```

contains the following, which may or may not be relevant

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 8086:0152, driver i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/andrew/.drirc: No such file or directory.
...
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0
```

X log is pretty verbose so have attached it here: [Xorg.0.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmazwu265nkt48j/Xorg.0.log)

Comment: Please, upload the xorg.log to a pastebin service. I can't see it in dropbox.

Comment: Xorg log also available here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7489220/

Comment: OP filed a bug report here https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78922

Answer (score 1):

Created an `/etc/xorg.conf` file and added the following option to the Device section after reading `man intel`

```
Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
```

This has removed the speckling artifacts, though I'm still having some GL render issues - that's a different problem.

---

**Editors Addition**

OP filed a [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78922) and this description is from that thread

> Ok it looks like the two issues are distinct.
>
> - Speckling disappears by changing the kernel module's acceleration method to UXA, but is unaffected by any of the Mesa version changes
> - GL rendering artifacts clear up on reverting to Mesa 9.0.3 ( and reappear after 9.1 ) but are unaffected by the kernel module's acceleration method.

Comment: I have logged a bug with xorg here : https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78922